# beautifulsoup returns none when using find() for an element

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, nonetype

I'm trying to scrape this site to retrieve the years of each paper thats been published. I've managed to get titles to work but when it comes to scraping the years it returns none.

I've broken it down and the results of 'none' occur when its going into the for loop but I can't figure out why this happens when its worked with titles.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://dblp.org/search?q=web%20scraping"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
results = soup.find(class_="publ-list")
paperResults = results.find_all(class_="data tts-content")
for singlepaper in paperResults:
    paperyear = singlepaper.find(class_="datePublished")
    print(paperyear)
```

When it goes to paperResults it gives the breakdown of the section I've selected within the results on the line above that.
Any suggestions on how to retrieve the years would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you mean: `paperyear = singlepaper.find("span", itemprop="datePublished")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
for singlepaper in paperResults:
    paperyear = singlepaper.find(class_="datePublished")
    print(paperyear)
```

To this

```
for singlepaper in paperResults:
    paperyear = singlepaper.find('span', itemprop="datePublished")
    print(paperyear.string)
```

You were looking for a class when you needed to be parsing span... if you print `paperResults` you will see that your `datePublished` is an `itemprop` in a `span` element.

Comment: This is just what I needed thanks! I feel like I tried this before and it printed something completely different, however its working how I intend now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://dblp.org/search?q=web%20scraping"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
results = soup.find(class_="publ-list")
paperResults = results.find_all(class_="data tts-content")
for singlepaper in paperResults:
    paperyear = singlepaper.find(attrs={"itemprop": "datePublished"})
    print(paperyear)
```

It worked for me.

Comment: This works well and is a great solution but it leaves the html still in the print results, the solution by Sinux1 removes this.  Thank you :)